# Чекер номеров в телеграм на python

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

Можно реализовать на питоне чекер по базе номеров? Ну или может на другом языке.
Имеется база клиентов, нужно оценить необходимость реализации бота.
Может кто подскажет пример для auth.checkPhone?

Comment: Какова задача этого чекера?

Comment: Проверить, использует ли пользователь телеграм.

Answer (score 1):

Есть 2 лимита: на общее количество контактов, и ограничение для предотвращения брутфорса.
Первый лимит — 10 000, если мне не изменяет память.
Второй лимит — что-то около 5000.

API возвращает список успешно добавленных контактов, список незарегистрированных номеров, и список номеров, которые не были проверены — их добавление клиент должен запросить позже.

Как-то ради эксперимента я попробовал добавить 10000 номеров. Сервер прислал около 200 новых контактов, 4800 номеров, которые не зарегистрированы в TG, и ещё 5000 номеров для повторного запроса.

Вот только повторный запрос естественно ничего не дал — ни один контакт не был обработан.

Я попробовал удалить часть контактов и отправить новый запрос — безрезультатно. Причем те контакты, которые сервер уже обработал до этого, продолжали обрабатываться. А любые другие, включая 5000 изначально необработанных просто игнорировались — сервер их не добавлял.

На следующий день я всё ещё не мог добавлять контакты. Больше не проверял, надоело